# i must develop a java class that invoke maven command automaticly

Tags: java, maven-2

i must develop a java class that invoke maven  command automaticly  like install ,deploy , compile ....  but i can't found the convinient java api  any idea  ???

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Maven Embedder Runtime](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0-beta-3/maven-embedder) (eg., [its own entry point](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/maven-3/tags/maven-3.0-beta-3/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.java?view=markup))

Comment: have you an exemple to run mvn install for exemple or thing like this ?

Comment: @trabelsi houcem

Simply call using args set as an array with a single element ('install')